# DI / IoC Abstract Factory Galore

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection

Given a project architecture as follows, where each box represents an assembly (all are class libraries), and each arrow stands for a dependency:

[image: architecture]

Might be worth nothing that this project is **massive** (well, it will become!), the complexity incurred by such decoupling is absolutely warranted.

**Business Logic Layer**

The BLL library defines and organizes various sets of POCO **interfaces** in its `Abstract` namespaces, and implements various functionality *logic* in its `Concrete` namespaces; the functionality logic refers to and uses the abstract POCO interfaces.

**Data Access Layer**

The DAL library implements the POCO interfaces from the BLL using `partial` classes that "extend" Linq to SQL (dbml) classes, so if there's a `Customer` L2S class, it implements the BLL `ICustomer` interface. Sometimes the L2S class has different types, or the BLL abstraction uses `enum` types, but most often the partial class code looks like this:

```
public partial class SomeEntity : ISomeEntity { }
```

This assembly provides the *Model*, by exposing classes named "xxxxModel", which are constructor-injected with *repositories* regrouped into *services*, but there's a twist: the "xxxxxModel" classes implement an interface called `IUnitOfWork` which encapsulates a database transaction that **must** be able to operate on all repositories at its disposal... possibly with a dynamic (runtime-determined) connection string. To achieve this, I created "model factories" which create a single `DataContext` of the appropriate type, and inject the same instance in each repository.

**Presentation Logic Layer**

Some of the BLL POCO interfaces need a "ViewModel" implementation (e.g. to display as items in a list) - the PLL library defines them; however the goal of this library is more focused around, well, the actual presentation logic, **although there is no reference to WPF whatsoever** (other than a single reference to *WindowBase* but I'll get to that). So this assembly provides the *ViewModel*.

One thing to note is that the ViewModel here, completely *controls* the View - each ViewModel is injected with an implementation of `IViewFactory` that creates an `IView` implementation - technically the ViewModel is blissfully unaware of the implementations, so I'm not sure how deeply it violates MVVM (to be honest I don't really care about that point - especially after reading a [blog post like this one](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.ca/2011/05/mvvm-backlash.html)), but the thing to point out is that it's the ViewModel that litterally *creates* the View and assigns the `DataContext`. This makes it very simple to deal with things that *should* be simple, such as showing and [closing a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376475/wpf-mvvm-how-to-close-a-window).

So all ViewModel classes inherit `ViewModelBase`, which is an abstract class that takes a `IViewFactory` in its protected constructor, effectively instantiating the View. Here's the offending code:

```
/// <summary>
/// An interface for a ViewModel.
/// </summary>
public interface IViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies listener that the value of the specified property has changed.
    /// </summary>
    void NotifyPropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property);

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies listener that the value of the specified property has changed.
    /// </summary>
    void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the view.
    /// </summary>
    void Close();

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the view.
    /// </summary>
    void Show();

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the view (modal) and returns a <see cref="DialogResult"/> value indicating how the view was closed.
    /// </summary>
    DialogResult ShowDialog();
}
```

So a ViewModel essentially *controls* a View up to the point of *encapsulating* it, which makes it easy to implement my own `DialogResult` enumeration (much closer to the way WinForms had it).

**Views Assembly**

Because this library references and consumes ViewModels from the PLL assembly which implement interfaces defined in the BLL assembly, an arrow is missing here - there's also a dependency upon the BLL, but it's only used indirectly. This library provides the *View*, by defining WPF/XAML windows and controls.

Apart from `IValueConverter` and other `MarkupExtension` implementations, there's not much C# code in this library, the hard references to ViewModel implementations are all in XAML `d:DataContext {d:DesignInstance...}` declarations.

**So, what's wrong?**

I definitely like the direction of the dependencies, including the PLL/Views one. The fact that the BLL has zero dependencies mean I can reuse that library and come up with a WebUI if I ever need one (and that WILL happen... eventually!), and the DAL/BLL decoupling means parts of the data model could be coming from Web services, some cloud, or whatever - business logic couldn't care less and that's good.

The main issue I'm having, is that I find myself writing LOTS of abstract factories, and implementing even more of them, and I'm not always reusing these abstractions (hence the smell), but it seems to me like whenever I ask myself how I can inject a "dynamic" dependency, the answer is almost automatically - "an abstract factory will do!"... which is probably right, it's just that I don't think it's right that pretty much everything is a "dynamic" dependency!

```
public class SomeViewFactory : IViewFactory
{
    public IView Create(IViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return new SomeWindow {DataContext = viewModel};
    }
}

public class SomeRepositoryFactory : DataRepositoryFactory<SomeEntity>
{
    public IRepository<SomeEntity> Create(DataContext context)
    {
        return new SomeRepository(context);
    }
}
```

I even have an abstract `IFunctionalityFactory`:

```
public interface IFunctionalityFactory
{
    IFunctionality Create();
}

public class SomeFunctionalityFactory : IFunctionalityFactory
{
    private readonly IFunctionalityAuth _auth;
    private readonly ISomeBusinessLogic _logic;

    public SomeFunctionalityFactory(IFunctionalityAuth auth, ISomeBusinessLogic logic)
    {
        _auth = auth;
        _logic = logic;
    }

    public IFunctionality Create()
    {
        var canExecute = auth.IsCurrentUserAuthorised(typeof(SomeFunctionality).FullName);
        return new SomeFunctionality(canExecute, _logic);
    }
}
```

Is it normal to have factories for almost everything - from repositories to services and models in the DAL, to Views and ViewModels in the PLL/View library? For now the project is rather small and I'm still the only programmer working on it; I'd like to have an architecture as SOLID and simple as possible when it comes to implementing new functionalities.

This is only my 2nd project implementing DI/IoC, needless to say I'm trying to run (and swim, and perhaps even fly) before I can walk...

Any tips or issues I'm not seeing? Am I abusing *Abstract Factory*? How else could I instantiate a View? How else could I have a data model that could connect to any of a given set of [almost] identical databases, at the user's discretion? I know I'm breaking MVVM, have I overlooked anything in the pattern that could simplify my existence?

Comment: Are you using any IOC container (Ninject, Castle Windsor, etc.)?  A container that can resolve dependencies would remove the need to define so many abstract factories.

Comment: I'm using Ninject, with Conventions and Interception extensions. I've never used as many abstract factories as with an IoC container! What's going on? (about to post an edit with some factory code)

Comment: Why don't you use ninject's `Kernel.Get<T>()` to resolve a dependency instead of writing a factory?

Comment: Because that woukd mean passing the kernel around and using it as a *Service Locator*; I want to avoid having a Ninject.dll dependency anywhere else than in the CompositionRoot assembly.

Comment: You don't have to have a Ninject.dll dependency everywhere. Heve a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891371/dependency-resolution-in-onion-architecture/15199997#15199997) where I explain how to avoid that on an MVC app. Things should be possible on WPF app as well.

Comment: I'm waiting for IAbstractFactoryBuilderStrategyMaker to be defined. (I don't know the technologies you're using well, but the pieces of code you've posted so far absolutely _reek_ of pointless overengineering.)

Comment: It's actually the service locator I want to avoid. And it's not a WPF app, all assemblies are class libraries. @Donal I posted here before getting to that ;)

Comment: @MaxS funny, I gave you an upvote on that answer a couple weeks ago - that's where the CompositionRoot assembly came from, thanks!

Comment: I don't realy get what ur doing here... U say you are using Ninject, but you are not using Ninject for what it's supposed to be used (keeping track of ur dependencies)? Can you show the piece of code where you actually need that factory? Imho, Ninject should limit the required use of Factories (not that Factories will be complete useless, but the amount ur talking about sounds weird). Btw, you talk about a MASSIVE application, but as far as I can see, you are using a rather small architecture... (Or have u left out some parts? :) )

Comment: Why don't you inject your IView instances using your IoCC + Constructor injection? Atm I'm working on a project fully IOP and DI using IoCC (autofaq). Untill now we have never had the requirement to use a factory (or using the kernel as a ServiceLocator). So an example of how you are using you're actual dependencies would be cool :)

Comment: @FrederikP. The app is massive in the sense that the BLL breaks into a couple dozen sub-domains, each with a couple dozen functionalities; some with UI requirement, most without. At first I was injecting IView directly into the ViewModels' constructor, but that caused the default view constructor to be called before a ViewModel could exist, and messed up the bindings. In this case the factory is used to defer construction until all the dependencies are ready. I'll edit to add some actual usage.

Comment: So u are using the ViewFactory inside ur ViewModel? If so, you are hiding dependencies which is a well know issue when starting to work with DI... It is dangerous when hiding dependencies, future developers will not be thankful...

Comment: It seems you're happily ripping KISS and YAGNI to shreds here. My advice is don't come up with big design patterns up front, *refactor* to patterns. I.e., get a working implementation of a slice of functionality first, *then* consider using DPs **if needed**. Nothing good can come out of an architecture prematurely littered with complex (especially, creational) design patterns.

Comment: Let me just say that I am really glad I won't have to maintain this. The bigger a project is, the more the need to keep it as simple as possible. In my experience, complexity increases exponentially with the size of a project. you seem to have gotten lost in technology buzzwords and want to use them all. Don't. Step back and think about what you're doing, each of those buzzwords is only a means to an end, not an end in themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're struggling trying to create *objects that create objects*... wouldn't you be better off just creating objects ?

Ninject allows you to do so in a very simple way :

```
// Ninject module
Bind<IRepository<SomeEntity>>().To<SomeEntityRepository>();

// injected class
public class SomeService
{
  public SomeService(IRepository<SomeEntity> repository)
  {
    // ...
  }
}

// get instance of injected class
var someService = kernel.Get<SomeService>();
```

I can't see the benefit of an abstract factory **in addition to an IoC container** when you're creating objects based on basic, compile-time-known constraints such as in your `SomeViewFactory` and `SomeRepositoryFactory` examples.

The dynamic nature of `SomeFunctionalityFactory` would be more debatable, but when you think of it, do you really need to instantiate an object with the *built-in notion* that it will never be able to be used by the current user ? Wouldn't it make more sense to have the object evaluate user authorization *when the functionality is called* ?

Comment: U're using it as a ServiceLocator. Which is an anti-pattern, since u still hide dependencies.

Comment: Actually from the "answer" I supplied that's precisely what I ended up doing, only with convention-based bindings, so as new features (and repositories) are added I don't need to go back to the CompositionRoot assembly and manually configure bindings for the new repositories, as long as I follow the naming conventions. As for the "Functionality" auth, you're right, but there's more to it... this library needs to "fit in" with an existing VB6 code base that it's eventually going to be replacing (*one bite at a time*). The existing VB6 code must be able to know if it should show a button or not.

Comment: @FrederikP. This was a simplified example. In reality you would only get top level objects through the container. There's still at least one place at the root of your system where you need to have a "hidden dependency" though, it can't be injection forever.

Comment: Depends how you look at it, in MVC for example you can influence the DependencyResolver to resolve using ur ninject kernel. You then inmediatly start injecting your objects (from ninject) into the controllers. So there is no "hidden dependency" apart from registering your IOC Container to the framework (not 100% sure about wpf, but I assume it's possible aswell like in MVC)

Comment: @guillaume31 I see what you mean with *compile-time known constraints* - I think somewhere along the line I mixed up *dependencies* with simple ViewModel properties. That's how I ended up with a `MessageWindowViewModelFactory`.